# develop custom extension in magento, which processes image of product and tags with prominent color codes

Tags: magento

I have been struggling in figuring out how can I tag a product with a color and when a user selects color from color picker, user should get all the products tagged with particular color or near by hex codes.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any code?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to create two product attribute like `main_color` and `related_colors`, `main_color` should be a single selection input type and should be searchable while `related_color` should be `Multi-select`but not searchable. you can then assign one main color to the product and multiple related color shades. On frontend you have to custom code, get the `related_color` attribute value,extract all related color codes and fetch all products having `main_color` with that value.

Hope this makes some sense.